# Service Discovery on Aws : eureka vs aws solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Trying to understand, is there a need in euruka on aws? If not whast tools are used for service discovery?
How service can fetch endpoints of services without eureka?
If i want to run locally service and connect to service in aws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use ECS for microservices.

You don't really need a third party service discovery for ECS, because ECS provides by default a registry of service names, see: [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/microservices-on-aws/service-discovery.html).

Although, if you don't want to use what ECS offers, or you are using EKS, you can rely on Eureka to be an option.

Comment: Is there are a  way to fetch endpoints from ecs to service, like with eureka?

Comment: ECS uses Route53 under the hood for service discovery, you can fetch the endpoints from there. I should mention that Eureka was designed for Spring specifically. ECS and Route53 should work for any kind on service, so you should not expect such in-depth integration as Eureka would provide.